# Node-gyp build and rebuild error on centos

Tags: c++, node.js, centos

Getting below error when trying to build `node-gyp build`

> node-gyp build gyp info it worked if it ends with ok gyp info using
>   node-gyp@1.0.2 gyp info using node@0.10.35 | linux | x64 gyp info
>   spawn make gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
>   make: Entering directory `/root/node-latest-install/build'
>
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/binding/binding.o ../binding.cc:5:
>   error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘FunctionCallbackInfo’ with no
>   type ../binding.cc:5: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
>   ../binding.cc: In function ‘void Add(int)’: ../binding.cc:7: error: no
>   matching function for call to
>   ‘v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(v8::Isolate
>
>   *&)’ /root/.node-gyp/0.10.35/deps/v8/include/v8.h:473: note: candidates are: v8::HandleScope::HandleSco
>
>   pe(const v8::HandleScope&)
>   /root/.node-gyp/0.10.35/deps/v8/include/v8.h:448: note:
>
>   v8::HandleScope::HandleSco                           pe()
>   ../binding.cc:9: error: ‘args’ was not declared in this scope
>   ../binding.cc:10: error: ‘class v8::Isolate’ has no member named
>   ‘ThrowException’ ../binding.cc:11: error: ‘NewFromUtf8’ is not a
>   member of ‘v8::String’ ../binding.cc:15: error: ‘args’ was not
>   declared in this scope ../binding.cc:16: error: ‘class v8::Isolate’
>   has no member named ‘ThrowException’ ../binding.cc:17: error:
>   ‘NewFromUtf8’ is not a member of ‘v8::String’ ../binding.cc:21: error:
>   ‘args’ was not declared in this scope ../binding.cc:22: error: no
>   matching function for call to ‘v8::Number::New(v8::Isolate*&, double&)
>   ’ /root/.node-gyp/0.10.35/deps/v8/include/v8.h:1381: note: candidates
>   are: static v8::Local<v8::Numb                           er>
>   v8::Number::New(double) ../binding.cc: In function ‘void
>   Init(v8::Handle<v8::Object>)’: ../binding.cc:28: error: no matching
>   function for call to ‘SetMethod(v8::Handle<v8::Object>&, cons
>
>   t char [4], void (&)(int))’ make: ***
>   [Release/obj.target/binding/binding.o] Error 1 make: Leaving directory`
>   /root/node-latest-install/build' gyp ERR! build error gyp ERR! stack
>   Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2 gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.onExit
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:2
>   3) gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17) gyp ERR!
>   stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (child_process.js:820:12) gyp ERR! System Linux
>   2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64 gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "build" gyp ERR! cwd
>   /root/node-latest-install gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.35 gyp ERR! node-gyp
>   -v v1.0.2 gyp ERR! not ok

Comment: Are you binding.cc's author? It has many problems... if not maybe compiler environment issue...I guess

Comment: Yes the script used for binding.cc is

Comment: #include <node.h>

using namespace v8;

void Add(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  HandleScope scope(isolate);

  if (args.Length() < 2) {
    isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(
        String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Wrong number of arguments")));
    return;
  }

  if (!args[0]->IsNumber() || !args[1]->IsNumber()) {
    isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(
        String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Wrong arguments")));
    return;
  }

Comment: double value = args[0]->NumberValue() + args[1]->NumberValue();
  Local<Number> num = Number::New(isolate, value);

  args.GetReturnValue().Set(num);
}

void Init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "add", Add);
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, Init)

Comment: I am using GCC on the server

Comment: It worked on my local computer fine with windows OS